# How to output log to terminal from iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

Logging to Chrome is extremely slow for me to the point of being unusable so I'm trying to get it to log to the terminal instead. They provide a command `react-native log-ios` for this but it gives me this error:

> error Cannot read property 'udid' of null. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

which, like 99% of React Native errors, makes no sense to me.

Any idea how I can get this command to work? Or is there any system command, similar to `adb logcat` for Android, that I can use directly to print iOS Simulator log to the terminal?